# SSL with virtual hosts

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, ssl, virtualhost, varnish

I've 'inherited' a server setup which i don't quite understand.  The server is an ubuntu box with a number of virtual hosts.

I've checked out the config for each virtual host and there's no mention of ssl at at all.  However, when i visit each site in a browser and prefix https:// they all seem to work.

I've created my own virtual host and tried to access it using https but it didn't work.

Thus, my question is where might it be that these virtual hosts are configured to use ssl?  All the examples i've seen have the virtual hosts with ssl directives inside them.

Note - Varnish is also used on this set up.  It sits on port 80 and forwards http requests to apache which listens on 81.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What's the output from `apache2ctl -S`?

Comment: there are many possibility. are you sure ssl terminates at the server? what does this command show? sudo netstat -ltap | grep :443, if this does not show anything then ssl terminates somewhere else and your server is only serving plain http content.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas - @ShaneMadden the output are all my virtual hosts and johnshen64 there is nothing so i guess that yes the server is only serving plain http content

Comment: "It didn't work" is a lousy description of the problem. Did you get a certificate error? What happened?

Comment: The page just hung in a loading state

Comment: What does the varnish configuration say? Does it do anything with port 443 traffic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the configuration for your load balancer and see where it is forwarding SSL requests, and then add your virtual host definitions on that server also.  Keep in mind that the configuration for an SSL vhost is different from the config for a plain vhost; you have to specify the certificate and that it is SSL (just use the existing vhost configs as an example).

Comment: Thanks for this, it looks like the load balancer forwards SSL requests to the hosts on Port 80.  That helps somewhat but there is obviously another peice of configuration i'm missing somewhere..